# Universal links in iOS with C++ and SDL

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, sdl

I was tasked with adding support for universal links into our iOS app written in C++ with an additional complication that the app uses SDL 2 for wrapping iOS specific code (like the `AppDelegate`).

From my brief research SDL does not provide any API to get the url, or did I miss something ? Is there a way to get the URL from SDL without modifying SDL itself ?

If not, then at least an outline (a code snippet) of how to get the URL from Objective C to C++ would be nice, as my Objective-C knowledge is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I ended up modifying SDL and made a PR, see here: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/pull/8356 If that gets through then there will be `SDL_UNIVERSALLINK` that gets triggered on every new URL.